# Any way to stop Visual Studio adding 'throw new NotImplementedException' on new functions? Causes namespace conflicts with Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, visual-studio-2017

Yes, I know this is good practise normally but the problem in Unity is it causes the System namespace to be added which breaks several Unity classes such as Random unless I fully qualify them which is tedious :). Is there any way to disable it from adding the throw? I've tried searching for a snippet for it but have drawn a blank. This happens when doing 'Generate Method' from Alt-Enter after typing in 'DoSomething();'

[image]

Comment: What extensions do you have installed that have to do with C#, Unity, Monobehaviour, etc? It may be that one of those are messing with it because mine doesn't do this by default.

Comment: Are you using ReSharper? Basically just remove that line?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can change this default behavior by changing the snippet that creates it.   That snippet is located at the following location:  (caveat...this will change it across the board for VS2017)

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC#\Snippets\1033\Refactoring\MethodStub.snippet

Comment: Digging this up again, this doesn't work in Community editions of Visual Studio (2017 or 2019). Editing the snippet file has no effect (even renaming the Snippet folder itself or removing it) - they seem to be hard-coded?

Comment: Just tried this myself and it doesn't work for me either...no idea why unfortunately