# How can you disable auto-generation of the not implemented exception?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

When Visual Studio auto generates methods, often the line 
`throw new NotImplementedException()` is added. I understand the benefits of this feature. Is there a way of disabling it so you won't have to do the extra step of removing it every time?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Any way to stop Visual Studio adding 'throw new NotImplementedException' on new functions? Causes namespace conflicts with Unity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53519389/any-way-to-stop-visual-studio-adding-throw-new-notimplementedexception-on-new)